# Dynamics AX 2012 SSRS Report multivalue parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm using Dynamics AX 2012 & Visual Studio 2010 to create a RDP based SSRS report.
After changing a couple of my report parameters to Multi Value, I recieve a warning:

> Dataset parameter SiteId cannot be bound to report parameter MyDS_SiteId because they do not have the same MultiValue property.

This is what my RDP attribute currently looks like:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
class MyDPContract
{
     InventSiteId    siteId;
}


[DataMemberAttribute("SiteId")]
public InventSiteId parmSiteId(InventSiteId _siteId = siteId)
{
     siteId = _siteId;
     return siteId;
}
```

How do I resolve this?  Do I return an array of InventSiteID?  Is there a property I've not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I got working. I had problems loading my RDP in Visual Studio when I specified the Extended Data Type, so I just used String.

```
[DataContractAttribute]
class MyDPContract
{
     List siteId;
}


[DataMemberAttribute("SiteId"),
 AifCollectionTypeAttribute("return",Types::String)]
public List parmSiteId(List _siteId = siteId)
{
     siteId = _siteId;
     return siteId;
}
```